# Read only text box size increased size automatically

Tags: html, jsf, xhtml

I have the two text box(Using JSJ).

I have given txt box size as 50. It is working fine. Based on logic I have make one of the text to readonly disabled = true or disable = disabled. The read only text width is increasing its size.

When I inspect through f12,the size are showing 50 only,In inspect mode when i remove the 
disable = disabled,it is reducing to actual size

I checked by the sample.

```
<h:inputText value="test" type="text" size="50">  
</h:inputText>
<br/><br/>
<h:inputText value="tes1t" type="text" size="50" disabled="true"> 
</h:inputText>
```

[image]

I have pass the param to form as below :

Param

```
<ui:param name="validationMessageOnTheSameLine" value="true" />
<ui:param name="rowWidth" value="650px" />
<ui:param name="helpTextPaddingLeft" value="130px" />
<ui:param name="showAsterik" value="false" />
<ui:param name="showAsterikForUsername" value="false" />
<ui:param name="inputTextSize" value="50" />

<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: #{rowWidth}" id="emailValidated"
    columnClasses="#{columnClass1}, #{columnClass2}">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{uit.emailAddress}:" for="email">
        <h:outputLabel styleClass="asterik" value="*"
            rendered="#{showAsterik}" />
    </h:outputLabel>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="tableNoPadding">
        <h:inputText value="#{userBean.emailAddress}"  id="email"
            styleClass="ux-margin-right-1t" size="#{inputTextSize}"
            required="true" disabled="#{disableEmailInput}"
            requiredMessage="#{uitkem.valueRequired}"
            validatorMessage="#{uitkem.emailValidator}">
            <f:validator validatorId="emailValidator" />
        </h:inputText>
        <rich:message for="email" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Need to dislay both text box with same size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that these `<h:inputText>` are enclosed in `<h:form>`.

Also, you don't need to add `type="text"` in `<h:inputText>`.

From my test environment (JSF 2.2), both these inputs have the same size when rendered.

Comment: Hi Thrax,Still have the problem `<ui:param name="validationMessageOnTheSameLine" value="true" />
     <ui:param name="rowWidth" value="650px" /> 
     <ui:param name="helpTextPaddingLeft" value="130px" />
     <ui:param name="showAsterik" value="false" />
     <ui:param name="showAsterikForUsername" value="false" />
     <ui:param name="inputTextSize" value="50" ` ,I have pass the param to the form,